# How to send email properly - asynchronously? Mail never arrives

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I created a new MVC5 project in C#.

I have some model:

```
public class EmailFormModel
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Your name")]
    public string FromName { get; set; }
    [Required, Display(Name = "Your email"), EmailAddress]
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a Conctact.cshtml:

```
@model EMailSenderWebApp.Models.EmailFormModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SendEmailAsync", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form contact-form", @id = "form-div" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Send your comments.</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromName, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FromEmail, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FromEmail)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"  })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

So, as you can see, my form calls HttpPost method "SendEmailAsync" which is described in my Home controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SendEmailAsync(EmailFormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("stefan.cv5@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
        message.From = new MailAddress("stefan.cv5@gmail.com");  // replace with valid value
        message.Subject = "Your email subject";
        message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 587;
        client.EnableSsl = false;

        client.SendCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            client.Dispose();
            message.Dispose();

        };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            client.SendAsync(message, Tuple.Create(client, message)));
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I've tried with some example as

> await client.SendMailSync()
>   but as you probably know, async call gone and never returns (some more info about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389351/mail-sends-but-never-returns))

So, I've implemented like this, guided with [this stack-overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935427/smtpclient-sendasync-blocking-my-asp-net-mvc-request)

This executes all the way the method (returns the View at the end) but my email never gets into my inbox?

Maybe google has some firewall?

Comment: A few things here.  You likely want to use something other than `SmtpClient` since [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) its _obsolete_.  If you have to use `SmtpClient` I would recommend using async/await and the method that actually returns a `Task`: [`SendMailAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is you are never connecting your smtp client to the server. Normally this would throw an exception, however you are also attempting to send your mail message inside a thread pool worker without proper try/catch. There is no code anywhere to catch your exception, so it seems like nothing is happening.

Also see my edits below to put `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` inside `using` blocks so you don't have to manually call `.Dispose()`. This ensures resources are disposed even if an exception occurs while connecting or sending your message.

As others have mentioned the built in System.Net.Mail library isn't maintained any more. I recommend using [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) ([nuget link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit/)) as it is extremely well maintained and the owner is very responsive.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmailAsync(EmailFormModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Create IDisposable inside `using` block so you aren't on the hook for calling Dispose()
        // The same has been done with your MailMessage
        using(SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "");
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = false;

            // You were missing this before which
            // was causing the exception. But due
            // to the thread your email was sent from
            // the exception was not thrown from a context
            // where you could know about it at all.
            await client.ConnectAsync();

            using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("stefan.cv5@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
                message.From = new MailAddress("stefan.cv5@gmail.com");  // replace with valid value
                message.Subject = "Your email subject";
                message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;

                await client.SendAsync(message);
            }
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```